# String.split returning null when using a dot

Tags: java, arrays, string, nullpointerexception

I got this simple code:

```
String ip = "1.2.3.4";
String[] ipArray = ip.split(".");
System.out.println(ipArray[1]);
```

And `ipArray` is null by the time it hits `System.out.println` (throws null pointer exception).

My question is why does ipArray stay null even though I'm setting it to split on each of ip's .s?

Comment: You're splitting on any character, so all characters are being splitted on leaving nothing left in the array.  [string.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a regular expression.

Comment: Dot `.` means "any character" :) You need a "real dot" `[.]`

Comment: To be exact, depending on the mode (DOTALL), `.` will or will not match new line character.

Comment: might i add, if you were using python, you'd be pretty much 100% correct.  the python split command splits by a character (or regex, but it defaults to a char)

Comment: Just a tiny correction - this code will throw java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException exception, rather than NPE (as OP wrote). String#split never returns null. The issue here is that the result is an empty array.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use `ip.split("\\.");` and your problems will be solved. The problem is that [String#split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) receives a regular expression, the dot (.) symbol is a special character in regular expressions, so you need to escape it for it to be interpreted as a plain dot, also as the backslash is an escape character in Java, you have to escape it too.

Answer (score 42):

`.` is a special character in regular expressions, which is what is used to split a string.

To get around this, you need to escape the `.`. That leads us to `\.` Unfortunately, `\` is ALSO a special character in the java string, so that must also be escaped, to make `\\.`

Our "final" result is `ip.split("\\.");`

In a related issue, the whole process can be averted entirely. There's no sense in doing something that a standard library already has done for us.

Consider the following

```
byte[] ipOctets = InetAddress.getByName(ip).getAddress();
```

The only issue here is to remember that if you want the int value, you have to extract it with `&` like `int octet = ipOctets[0] & 0xFF;`

Answer (score 5):

[Pattern.quote(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) can also be used to quote the whole string. This returns a pattern which will be interpreted literally, special characters will have no special meaning. This might be overkill in this case, but sometimes it can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use split ("[.]")

```
String s = "abcd.jpg";
String[] strarry = s.split ("[.]");
```

strarry[0]=abcd,
strarry[1]=jpg