# replace all occurrences of a character in a string in java?

Tags: java

A very noob question..

I want to replace all the occurance of "." in a string with empty space..

So this is what I tried

```
             String s = "1.2.3.4";
        System.out.println(s);
         s = s.replaceAll(".", " ");
        System.out.println(s);
```

But the second print is an empty print?

What did i missed here?

Comment: Read the javadoc of `replaceAll`.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11457236/1065197

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You want to escape the `.`. Otherwise, it can match anything.

Try `s.replaceAll("\\.", " ")` instead.

Answer (score 10):

Use String.replace(char, char) instead of String.replaceAll